# Nodemailer authorization error with gmail

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, gmail, nodemailer

I tried to connect nodemailer to gmail. More specifically I want to connect the contact form with the backend. Despite numerous attempts to connect both services I keep getting ERROR. A message appears that the login and password do not match or are not accepted. I logged in to the browser and everything works. I followed carefully the directions for connecting nodemailer to gmail. It's about allowing the gmail to connect to less secure applications. I have turned off two-factor authentication in gmail. Unfortunately it still didn't help. My code below.

ContactForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("Submit");
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setStatus("Sending...");
    const { name, email, message } = e.target.elements;
    let details = {
      name: name.value,
      email: email.value,
      message: message.value,
    };
    let response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/contact", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(details),
    });
    setStatus("Submit");
    let result = await response.json();
    alert(result.status);
  };
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" required />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="message">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="message" required />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">{status}</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Index.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/", router);
app.listen(5000, () => console.log("Server Running"));

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: "*********@gmail.com",
    pass: "**********",
  }
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {


    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/contact", (req, res) => {
  const name = req.body.name;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message; 
  const mail = {
    from: name,
    to: "",
    subject: "Contact Form Submission",
    html: `<p>Name: ${name}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
});
```

After running server with Node.js

```
Server Running
Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w4sm11053143qkd.94 - gsmtp
    at SMTPConnection._formatError (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:774:19)
    at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:1513:34)
    at SMTPConnection.<anonymous> (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:540:26)  
    at SMTPConnection._processResponse (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:932:20)
    at SMTPConnection._onData (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:739:14)      
    at TLSSocket.SMTPConnection._onSocketData (D:\my-website\backend\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\smtp-connection\index.js:189:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials w4sm11053143qkd.94 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you turn of two-factor authorization, you also need to turn of the settings in your google account to allow less-secure apps. You can do it from  https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Then, it will give you a randomly generated password to use with Nodemailer. Your actual password doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

the google less-secure is no longer available. but u can use [two-Step](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/signinoptions/two-step-verification) Verification ! after Verifying Your Account u can add nodemailer to the  [App-passwords](https://myaccount.google.com/u/1/apppasswords) and set the 16-digit code to the createTransport auth